# Array shifted to the right, but index[0] is gone

Tags: java, arrays

I am shifting an array to the right,but when I do I am missing the original array[0].

```
int innerLastIndex = innerRotorClockWise.length - 1;

String innerOldLast = innerRotorClockWise[innerLastIndex]; 

for (int i = innerLastIndex; i != 0; i--) {

    //place a holder  for first and last. 

    innerRotorClockWise[i] = innerRotorClockWise[i-1];


    innerRotorClockWise[0] = innerOldLast;
```

Output:

original

```
[#, G, N, U, A, H]
```

shifted 1

```
[H, H, G, N, U, A]
```

shifted 2

```
[A, A, H, G, N, U]
```

I have look at others and they don't seem to help solve this. Do I have to  make a place holder for my first element as well or no?

Comment: I think that maybe you are not showing enough code.  Is this in a method that you are calling multiple times?

Comment: Yes, this is the whole method that I am calling multiple of times.

Comment: what is the correct output?

Comment: This cannot be the whole code, because you have an unbalanced start-brace `{`. Assuming the missing end-brace is after the shown code, that would be your problem, since the last statement should be after the loop, not inside it. Also, what you're attempting is a *rotate*, not a *shift*, and there are lots of examples for how to rotate an array out there, so a little effort searching for them would likely have given you an answer to your problem.

Comment: @AllenTran Not sure about the reason for downvote to my answer. Did you try it as I said?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have placed the following statement inside the loop:

```
innerRotorClockWise[0] = innerOldLast;
```

This causes the 0th element to be replaced in the first iteration itself. Close the loop after the first statement itself as:

```
for (int i = innerLastIndex; i != 0; i--) {

     innerRotorClockWise[i] = innerRotorClockWise[i-1];

}
innerRotorClockWise[0] = innerOldLast;
```

The following code works for me:

```
    String[] innerRotorClockWise = new String[]{"#", "G", "N", "U", "A", "H"};
    int innerLastIndex = innerRotorClockWise.length - 1;

    String innerOldLast = innerRotorClockWise[innerLastIndex];

    for (int i = innerLastIndex; i != 0; i--) {


        innerRotorClockWise[i] = innerRotorClockWise[i - 1];

    }
    innerRotorClockWise[0] = innerOldLast;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(innerRotorClockWise));
```

Comment: @AllenTran Not sure about the reason for downvote. Did you try it as I said?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a functioning implementation:

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int previous = array[0];
for (int i=1; i <= array.length; i++) {
    int temp = array[i % array.length];
    array[i % array.length] = previous;
    previous = temp;
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

**Output:**

```
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The key points here are that we store the number which will be replaced by each shift in a variable which lives *outside* the loop.  This previous value is what actually does the replacement.

There is also a mod trick here:

```
array[i % array.length] = previous;
```

This will replace the position `i` value of the array with the value which came before it.  However, the loop runs until the length of the array, at which point `i % array.length` will wrap around to the zero position.  Hence, we don't need any space edge cases to cover the first/last replacement.

Comment: I'm the down-voter and I'm doing that because this is a much less efficient solution than OPs almost working code. Simply moving OPs last statement outside the loop fixes it, and that code is much simpler. Faster too, since it doesn't have to calculate modulus all the time. But I'm curious: Why is OPs code a "bad approach"?

Comment: so, simple typo then

Comment: I had the same doubt. Why should we go for a modulus approach when it can be done with a subtraction?